# Python のパスを通すとき、システム環境変数に書かなければいけないのはなぜですか？

Tags: python, windows

以下、用語の使い方が間違っていたり、内容がわかりにくい点は遠慮なくご指摘いただけますと助かります。
後学のために忌憚なきご意見よろしくお願いいたします。

### 環境

- OS: Windows10

### 質問

Python のチュートリアル等で `python` コマンドが使えない場合に、原因および解決法としてよく書かれているのは**システム環境変数**の `PATH` への登録ですが、なぜ**ユーザー環境変数**の `PATH` ではないのでしょうか？

ユーザー環境変数の `PATH` に登録したところうまくいかず、コマンドプロンプトで `eho %PATH%` を確認すると、ユーザー環境変数の `PATH` に登録したはずの内容が表示されていませんでした。

上記質問の考えられる理由としては以下のどれかと推測していますが、理由が明記されているような情報にたどり着けないため質問させてください。

- `python` とたたくとシステム環境変数しか見に行かないから
- `python` は `PATH`を見に行く（i.e. OS のルールに従って生成されたシステム環境変数＋ユーザー環境変数）が、 本来であれば `PATH` にユーザー環境変数の内容も反映されるはずなのにされていないから

### 質問者の理解

- `python` コマンドなどのパスを通すためには、`python.exe` などが格納されているディレクトリのパスを環境変数 `PATH` に登録する必要がある
- Windows のコマンドプロンプトで環境変数の更新を反映させるためには、プロンプトの再起動が必要
- （管理者権限でない）通常の権限でコマンドプロンプトを使用している場合、環境変数 `PATH` 以外はユーザー環境変数が優先される
- （管理者権限でない）通常の権限でコマンドプロンプトを使用している場合、環境変数 `PATH` はシステム環境変数＋ユーザー環境変数として設定されており、重複する内容があれば先に読み込まれている方が優先される（i.e. システム環境変数にかかれていればそちらが優先される

Comment: 「ユーザー環境変数の `PATH` に登録したところうまくいかず」は間違ってる気がします。`set PATH=%PATH%;Pythonのパス` の様に追加しその場で Python起動すれば起動するはず (なのでユーザー環境変数かシステム環境変数かは(この場合)関係ない)

Comment: 「ユーザー環境変数の PATH に登録したところ」というのは具体的には何をされたのでしょうか？（どんなツールを使って何をどう操作したのか？）Windowsの場合、環境変数を反映するのにPCの再起動が必要な場合があります。

Comment: 「質問者の理解」の部分はおおむねそれで良いと思われますが、何を如何したかを具体的に書いていないので、あまり厳密ではないかもしれません。そして「質問」の部分で登録したけどその内容が表示されないとか推測の部分とかは、これも具体的に書かれていないので、多分何か手順を間違えたか抜かしたかしていると思われます。推測している部分はコマンドプロンプトやOSの動作も混じっているのでこれも厳密ではありません。あと参考にしている記事が必ずしも正確だとは言えないので注意してください。`PATH`についてはコマンドプロンプトではなくスタートメニューの「設定」などからのGUIで編集した方が良いでしょう。

Comment: @kunif 質問方法への有益なご指摘ありがとうございます。確かに具体性が欠けるので回答がしづらい内容になっていますね。もう一度再現実験とGUIでの設定を行ってみようと思います。

Comment: @merino GUI で登録を行いました。ただ、少し時間が経っており、ご指摘の再起動の件も含めて詳細を精査してみようと思います。それでもわからない場合は再度質問をさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

> 質問 Python のチュートリアル等で python
> コマンドが使えない場合に、原因および解決法としてよく書かれているのはシステム環境変数の PATH への登録ですが、なぜユーザー環境変数の
> PATH ではないのでしょうか？

システム環境変数でもユーザー環境変数でもどちらでも大丈夫です。

システム環境変数は全ユーザで有効となりますが、ユーザー環境変数は特定のユーザだけで有効となります。
※質問された方が参照されたページが何かわかりませんが、ユーザー環境変数ではダメ、システム環境変数でなければダメとは書いていないはずです。

> ユーザー環境変数の PATH に登録したところうまくいかず、コマンドプロンプトで eho %PATH% を確認すると、ユーザー環境変数のPATH に登録したはずの内容が表示されていませんでした。

環境変数を設定した後に新たに「コマンドプロンプト」を起動すれば確認ができるはずです。既に起動済みの「コマンドプロンプト」には新たに追加変更された環境変数が反映されません。

※ `eho %PATH%`は`echo %PATH%`の誤りですよね。

> 質問者の理解
>
> - python コマンドなどのパスを通すためには、python.exe などが格納されているディレクトリのパスを環境変数PATH に登録する必要がある

はい、私の認識と同じです。

> - Windows のコマンドプロンプトで環境変数の更新を反映させるためには、プロンプトの再起動が必要

はい、必要です。環境変数の変更前に起動したプログラムには反映できません。

> - （管理者権限でない）通常の権限でコマンドプロンプトを使用している場合、環境変数 PATH 以外はユーザー環境変数が優先される

いいえ、システム環境変数やユーザー環境変数の違いは全ユーザで有効になるか、設定したときのユーザだけで有効になるかの違いです。

> - （管理者権限でない）通常の権限でコマンドプロンプトを使用している場合、環境変数 PATHはシステム環境変数＋ユーザー環境変数として設定されており、重複する内容があれば先に読み込まれている方が優先される（i.e.> システム環境変数にかかれていればそちらが優先される

いいえ、管理者権限の有り無しは今回の問題とは無関係だと思います。
システム環境変数とユーザー環境変数のPathはシステム環境変数として登録されたものが優先されました。

---

追記

環境変数に定義できる最大長が決まっており、システム環境変数が長過ぎるとユーザー環境変数が切り捨てられることがあるようです。